# I want to add local variable in Angular but error occur "type 'string null' is not assignable to type 'string'. typescript"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, variables, angularjs-scope

This is an image what exactly, i am facing the problem "type 'string null' is not assignable to type 'string'. typescript"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I simply add This =>

```
localItem: string | null;
```

and finally it's working!

Answer (score 0):

add '?' after type
`localItem:string?;`

Comment: localItem:string?; this is not working instead of that i'm adding this localItem: string | null;